# Add clicked on HorizontalStackLayout in .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, maui

I am making an application with the .net maui framework

With buttons, it is possible to add the `Clicked` argument to call a function. But I would like to apply it on a group of elements like `HorizontalStackLayout` or other than a button like `Label` and `Image`.

```xml
<ContentPage ...>
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <HorizontalStackLayout>
                <Image Source="assets/profil/EnzoDeg40.png" />
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    <Label Text="EnzoDeg40"/>
                    <Label Text="On mange des frites ce soir ?"/>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
            ...
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: use a [Gesture Recognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/tap?view=net-maui-7.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason) mentions, add a [Gesture Recognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/tap?view=net-maui-7.0) as a child allows you to add an "OnClick" to a group

```xml
<HorizontalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnCounterClicked"/>
</HorizontalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
```